# How do I find and install Kodi 16.1 Jarvis package on Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, kodi

This is the error I get:-

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kodi : Depends: kodi-bin (>= 2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: kodi-bin (< 2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know why but the package Kodi 16.1 Jarvis is nowhere to be found since V17 has poked into the scene.

Comment: Your question has several issues: 1. It's a nonsensical rant and 2. has **nothing** to do with Ubuntu. Kodi is **not** part of Ubuntu although now is also available in the official repositories. That doesn't mean Canonical can (or should) do something about the Kodi versions release. That's entirely up to Kodi devs.

Comment: Classic newbie imprinting: 'Ubuntu is a defective because it doesn't work like Windows'. Ubuntu is *not* a centrally-designed OS like Windows. Ubuntu is a conglomeration of thousands of open source upstream projects. A .deb is unlike an .exe or .msi. A deb is valid only with the release of Ubuntu that it is built for, and is usually incompatible with others. Your 'held broken packages' message means you have broken your system by trying to install incompatible packages - google the message. We were all new once, and we all overcame the problems you currently have.

Comment: OK ... so in order for me to use this Kodi pckage I have to buy new equipment?

Comment: You can install Kodi from the official repository: http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/kodi Install it and its depends:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu, only 1 version of application is available at the same time. There are exceptions, but they are few. So, generally, if Ubuntu updated to Kodi 17, you won't find 16 in the repos.
Your only option would be to find older package and all its dependencies, install it with dpkg and lock the version update. 
However, Kodi team seems to provide thier own repository with a previous release available. To use it, remove the current stable PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
```

Then install the old stable version with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/kodi-old
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove kodi*
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

Comment: Thankx ... but this still fails.  I was using this Dual 2.5 GHz 2G RAM LapTop for Kodi and TV stuff.  I can't use the latest version of Kodi 17 because it is built around newer computer equipment and lags as to be useless.  I tried to install OpenELEC but that didn't work either.  I was hoping that Linux was the answer to WindoZe bloat, expense and inefficiency.  Thankx for your efforts and posts on my behalf.  It would be so nice to be RICHER!!

Comment: How does any of this matter for the question?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching myself on Jarvis and the difficulty of finding thereof --

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/kodi-old
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xbmc=2:[INSERT VERSION NUMBER HERE]* 
xbmc-bin=2:[INSERT VERSION NUMBER HERE]*
```

In my case it was:

```
sudo apt-get install kodi=2:16* kodi-bin=2:16*
```

<sup>([source](http://airbornesurfer.com/2015/04/how-to-install-previous-versions-of-kodi-xbmc-in-ubuntu-linux/))</sup>

Comment: Important Note: its a different PPA for `kodi-old` then the regular ppa

Answer (score -1):

You can try to install an older version of Kodi by typing

```
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

on the terminal without installing a ppa.

I currently have Ubuntu 16.04.2 installed and this is what I get:

```
$ apt-cache policy kodi
kodi:
  Installed: 2:17.0~git20170210.1529-final-0xenial
  Candidate: 2:17.0~git20170210.1529-final-0xenial
  Version table:
 *** 2:17.0~git20170210.1529-final-0xenial 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     15.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

As you can see I have the ppa installed and that gives me the lastest version. If you type the following command without installing the kodi ppa you should be able to get an older version.

Update after comment:

Kodi has not been updated om the main repos. Actually the main repo is still at 15.2 ! To double check on an older laptop (with 16.1 installed):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
# (Some output)
$ apt-cache policy kodi
kodi:
  Installed: 2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial
  Candidate: 2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial
  Version table:
 *** 2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     15.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

So by having Ubuntu 16.04 you can get Kodi 15.2. I am not sure (haven't tested it) if you can get kodi 16.1 by installing 16.10. (One can propably test it by trying a live USB.)

Comment: You are wrong. See my update where I removed ppa to double check on my other laptop (that still has 16.1). Even without that the output from apt-cache on the first place should tell you that 15.2 is the avalilable version. Hence it is FAR from being updated!!!